# Bootstrap 4 tool tip is not showing in style. Also it is only working for anchor tags

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip, ejs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using bootstrap 4 and want to show tooltip on my buttons and anchor tags. But tooltip is showing only on anchor tags but not on buttons. Even when tooltip does displays it does not show any styling means it is white and not look anything like as in Bootstrap Docs.

Heres my code it is an ejs template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Lab Management System">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/card.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/progressbar.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
        <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background: #31353D; color: #c5c6c7">
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" style="border-color: #66fcf1;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span style="color: azure"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
              </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="/" class="nav-link" style="color: azure">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form id="my_form" method="post" action="/logout">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline my-2 my-sm-0 btnLogout" style="border-color: #66fcf1;color:#c5c6c7; background-color: transparent" type="submit">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <% include ../../include/sidebar %>


            <main class="page-content">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px;">
                                <thead class="bg-primary" style="color: white">
                                    <tr style="LINE-HEIGHT:15px">
                                        <th class="center">
                                            Case ID
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Patient Name</th>
                                        <th>Phone no</th>
                                        <th>Patient ID</th>
                                        <th>Reporting Date</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        <th>Paid</th>
                                        <th>Due</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    <% if(cases) {  
                                            cases.forEach(singleCase => { %>
                                        <tr style="LINE-HEIGHT:15px">

                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <%= singleCase.case_no %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <%= singleCase.patient_name %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <%= singleCase.patient.phone %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <%= singleCase.patient_id %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <%= singleCase.reporting_date %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480 text-center">




                                                <% if (singleCase.result_status == 1) { %>
                                                    <span class="badge badge-sm badge-warning">Received</span>
                                                    <% } %>
                                                        <% if (singleCase.result_status == 2) { %>
                                                            <span class="badge badge-sm badge-info">Conducted</span>
                                                            <% } %>
                                                                <% if (singleCase.result_status == 3) { %>
                                                                    <span class="badge badge-sm badge-success">Approved</span>
                                                                    <% } %>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <% if (singleCase.result_status == 1) { %>
                                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="form-field-6" href="/getcasedetails/<%= singleCase.id %>" title="Click to add results">
                                                        <span class="badge badge-sm badge-info">Add Result</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <% } %>
                                                        <% if (singleCase.result_status == 2) { %>
                                                            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="form-field-6" href="#" title="Click to approve results">
                                                                    <span class="badge badge-sm badge-success">Approve Result</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                            <% } %>
                                                                <% if (singleCase.result_status == 3) { %>
                                                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="form-field-6" href="#" title="Click to disapprove results">
                                                                            <span class="badge badge-sm badge-danger">Disapprove</span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    <% } %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480 text-center">
                                                <%= Math.ceil( singleCase.total ) %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="hidden-480 text-center">
                                                <%= Math.ceil( singleCase.paid ) %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td <% if(singleCase.due> 0){ %> class="text-danger text-center font-weight-bold"
                                                <% } %>
                                                    <% if(singleCase.due == 0){ %> class="text-center text-success font-weight-bold"
                                                        <% } %>>
                                                            <%= Math.ceil( singleCase.due ) %>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <% })
                                            }  %>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.page-content -->

                </div>
            </main>
            <!-- page-content" -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-wrapper -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dynamic-table').DataTable();
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();


        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**So far what I can confirm is that**

- Order of poper, jquery and bootstrap js is right
- Tooltip is initialized inside jquery document ready function for all elements
- `data-toggle="tooltip"` is present inside both elements

Answer (score 1):

Is that the code you are using? The current code works on all my browsers (EI, Edge, FF, and Chrome). What browser are you using and is the JS enabled?

Here is a working code based on your example: jsfiddle.net/zergioz/tbgrfv4z - hover over the different status.

Comment: That was not my original code. now I had added my original code in question it contains one button and one anchor tag. Can you point problem in that

Comment: for what I can tell, your issues are the "quotations " here is a working code based on your example: https://jsfiddle.net/zergioz/tbgrfv4z/  - hover over the different status.

Comment: Yes, this fiddle works great but can you point exactly what quotations?

Comment: This part: { %> title="Click to Add Results " <% } try re-writing it. make it dynamically by setting the value into a variable the rendering it instead of doing it in-line. I hope it works!

Comment: I had updated the code inside question please check

Comment: It does work in your fiddle but when I copy paste your code inside my ejs file It does not work. Maybe due to ejs extension as your code is in html file

Comment: Your answer has not solved my problem but maybe helpful to someone else in the future. Thank you very much for your sincere effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. If you want the tooltip on top make sure to put top inside the data-placement attribute and also ensure that you have enough space above the button to display the tooltip.

https://codepen.io/plumwd/pen/qeGbyM

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

     <br><br><br><br><br> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
                                Tooltip on top
                              </button>
      <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="form-field-6" title="Tooltip here" href="#"><span>Click</span> </a>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();


        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had added my original code in question it contains one button and one anchor tag. Can you point problem in that

Comment: The only issue I saw is that the tooltip placement was set to the right and was positioned at the very top of the screen. Because of that, even if the placement were "top" the tooltip would position elsewhere.

Comment: The top is not the position it is the text that displays inside the tooltip. Position of the tooltip is right while text inside tooltip is `Tooltip on top`